# Unable to call IntentIntegrator class from ZXing?

Tags: android

Android newbie here. I recently started to build a barcode scanner apps and I stumbled on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe7F4Jx7rwo). However, I have problem following the video when the IntentIntegrator class came out. My code seems unable to import the class even though I already implement ZXing in the build.gradle(Module:app).

Here is my code for build.gradle(Module.app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scanner4"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@arr'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And this is my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.scanner4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button scan_btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
        final Activity activity = this;

        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContent() != null){
                Toast.makeText(this,"You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


    }
}
```

My problem is with line:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
```

I would really appreciate your help on this matter as I am completely new in Android. Please forgive me for my inexperience as I can't find any solution for this simple issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** This line make your app cannot resolve `IntentIntegrator`.

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@arr'
```

To import an Android Archive Library (aar) in gradle, then you must you **@aar** instead of **@arr**.

**Solution:** Change the dependency in gradle file to

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any ZXing related `import` lines in your code, so possibly the reason. You need to add missing `import`s, easiest would by to try "Optimize imports" action <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to have that automatically corrected.